# How to convert a column in a pandas dataframe to datatime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a csv document, an example below:

```
oci,citing,cited,creation,timespan,journal_sc,author_sc
0200100000236252421370109080537010700020300040001-020010000073609070863016304060103630305070563074902,"10.1002/pol.1985.170230401","10.1007/978-1-4613-3575-7_2",1985-04,P2Y,no,no
```

There are 2 columns, representing dates, I want to change column type from string to `datetime` format.

The column `creation` (string) is the date of creation and can be expressed in three forms in addition to be unspecified:

1. "yyyy-mm-dd" (e.g. "2019-09-20")
2. "yyyy-mm" (e.g. "2019-09")
3. "yyyy" (e.g. "2019")

The column `timespan` (string): is represented according to the form `PnYnMnD`, where `P` is a literal value that starts the expression, `nY` is the number of years followed by a literal`Y`, `nM` is the number of months followed by a literal `M`, `nD` is the number of days followed by a literal `D`, where any of these numbers and corresponding designators may be absent if they are equal to 0.  A minus sign may appear before the `P` to indicate negative duration.

I am trying to change column type from string to `datetime` format using `pd.to_datetime()` function:

```
def do_process(f_path):
    global my_ocan

    my_ocan = pd.read_csv(f_path, names=['oci', 'citing', 'cited', 'creation', 'timespan', 'journal_sc', 'author_sc'], parse_dates = ['creation', 'timespan'])
    my_ocan['timespan'] = pd.to_datetime(my_ocan['timespan'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore', yearfirst=True)
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.to_datetime(my_ocan['creation'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore', yearfirst=True)
    #print(my_ocan['citing'])
    print(my_ocan.info())

    return my_ocan
```

When executing `print(my_ocan.info())` I get '214 non-null object' instead of `datetime`. What am I missing? What's the issue?

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 214 entries, 0 to 213
Data columns (total 7 columns):
oci           214 non-null object
citing        214 non-null object
cited         214 non-null object
creation      214 non-null object
timespan      214 non-null object
journal_sc    214 non-null object
author_sc     214 non-null object
dtypes: object(7)
```

Thank you and have an awesome day y'all :)

Comment: The problem is the mulltiple kind of input for "creation" column. 
It tries to convert it into a datetime type but it can't since there are different incoming values. It converts it into an object.
You can cast the collumn back to datetime but it will remove your values. You could use something like `myocan.astype({'creation': 'datetime64[ns]'}).dtypes`
to convert it to a datetime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues to address in your code.

First, notice that in your `.csv` file the first column is:

```
oci,citing,cited,creation,timespan,journal_sc,author_sc
```

So when you're building a database with `pd.read_csv` the first row of your dataframe will be the first row of your `.csv` file. You end up with your dataframe being :

```
                                                 oci  ...  author_sc
0                                                oci  ...  author_sc
1  0200100000236252421370109080537010700020300040...  ...         no
```

instead of :

```
[2 rows x 7 columns]
                                                 oci  ... author_sc
1  0200100000236252421370109080537010700020300040...  ...        no
```

I don't think you want that.

You also suppress errors with `pd.to_datetime` which isn't great. Once you remove `errors='ignore'`, you'll notice that the conversion to `datetime` fails because the input doesn't match the `'%Y%m%d'` format.

And of course it doesn't since your `creation` column is:

```
0    creation
1     1985-04
```

And the first row is `"creation"` which doesn't match `'%Y%m%d'`.

Second, the date format should be `'%Y-%m-%d'`, since the dates are of a YYYY-MM-DD format and not YYYYMMDD. 
(Careful, because when your format has days in it for example and the input doesn't, a day is added to the date).

Third, the `timespan` values aren't dates, they're periods (a Java period if I'm not mistaken), so using `pd.to_datetime` on them doesn't work. I haven't found a python function that does the conversion for you so you might have to do the work yourself in a good old string parsing fashion, or dig deeper in python libs.

Fourth, as the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) says, `pd.to_datetime` is deprecated so you'd do well to stay away and use for example `datetime.strptime` instead which does a very similar job.

Finally, here's a working version of your code:

```
 def do_process(f_path):
     global my_ocan

     my_ocan = pd.read_csv(f_path, names=['oci', 'citing', 'cited', 'creation', 'timespan', 'journal_sc', 'author_sc'], parse_dates = ['creation', 'timespan'])
     my_ocan = my_ocan.iloc[1:]  # to remove the first row
     my_ocan['creation'] = pd.to_datetime(my_ocan['creation'], format="%Y-%m-%d", yearfirst=True)
     # Period parsing on my_ocan['timespan']
     print(my_ocan.info())

     return my_ocan
```

Which outputs:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 1 to 1
Data columns (total 7 columns):
oci           1 non-null object
citing        1 non-null object
cited         1 non-null object
creation      1 non-null datetime64[ns]
timespan      1 non-null object
journal_sc    1 non-null object
author_sc     1 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(6)
```

Notice `creation` is of type `datetime64[ns]` now.

Comment: Chris, thank you very much for a detailed explanation and directing my thoughts on the right track! :)